# HTTP Status 500 For Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 on Centos 6.3

Tags: java, tomcat, centos6

I have installed Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 on my centos 6.3. While opening centos server from remote machine I get following error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:423)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:282)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 logs.
```

My CATALINA_HOME and other variables are set properly.

Comment: Alright I get tomcat welcome page after appending :8080 at the end of server IP but when I hit serverip:8080/myApp it gives 404 error